# clearInterval not working - Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, setinterval, clearinterval

I also tried rxjs with no luck, so I assume there is something in my code that I just can't see.
The following function "play" is only called once.

```
play() {
    console.log('played'); //only logged once
    this.mainPlayButton = false;
    let media = this.media.create(this.conversation[this.currentAudio].audio);
    media.play(this.opts);

    this.timer = window.setInterval(()=>{
      media.getCurrentPosition().then((pos) => {
        this.conversation[this.currentAudio].time = pos / media.getDuration();
        if (pos == -1) {
          this.conversation[this.currentAudio].time = 1;
          media.release();
          if (this.currentAudio == this.conversation.length - 1) {
            this.stop();
          }
          else {
            this.currentAudio++;
            this.play();
          }
        }
      });
    }, 100);

  }
```

And the "stop" function is called infinite times, even though this is where the timer is cleared. The timer obviously isn't cleared.

```
stop() {
    console.log('stopped'); //logs infinitely
    this.mainPlayButton = true;
    window.clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
```

All help is appreciated! I've been stuck for an hour now and its boggling my mind.

Comment: are you sure play() is only triggered once? if it's triggered twice then the second setInterval will override the first one and that will explain the behavior you are seeing (it's the simplest explanation)

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the "played" log is only in the console once

Comment: my only thought is for you to print the interval id when setting it and just before you clearInterval - that way you will be sure you are clearing the correct interval (maybe somewhere on the way you are overriding the value on this.timer) - simply console.log(this.timer) just after setting and just before clearing

Comment: Yes you are correct, when I was invoking the play function the second time the global timer variable was being overwritten. I simply cleared the interval before invoking the play function the second time.

Comment: cheers, happy to help